# Mid sentence carriage return with regex

Tags: r, regex

I have text as follows.

```
mytext<-c("There is a\nlot of stuff","There is a\nlot of stuff\n","There is a\n lot of stuff","Stuff is everywhere\n\n\n\n around here. Clean it\n up")
```

I'd like to get rid of the \n in the middle of the sentence with the output being:

```
There is a lot of stuff
There is a lot of stuff\n
There is a lot of stuff
Stuff is everywhere around here. Clean it up
```

I have tried:

```
gsub("([a-z]\\s*)\n+(\\s*[a-z])", "\\1 \\2", mytext)
```

but it gives the output:

```
[1] "There is a lot of stuff"                              "There is a lot of stuff"                             
[3] "There is a  lot of stuff"                             "Stuff is everywhere\n\n\n  around here. Clean it  up"
```

I don't seem to be able to get rid of the mid sentence \n when there are multiples of them. Using the greedy operator with \n gives me odd results.

Comment: @akrun thanks. Example corrected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
gsub("(?:\\h*\\R)++(?!\\z)\\h*", " ", mytext, perl=TRUE)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lhtoXW/1/) and the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/0bHD2G).

**Details**

- `(?:\\h*\\R)++` - 1 or more occurrences (matched possessively thanks to `++` quantifier, so that no backtracking could occur into the non-capturing group pattern) of:

  - `\\h*` - 0 or more horizontal whitespaces.
  - `\\R` - any line break sequence
- `(?!\\z)` - not at the very end of string.
- `\\h*` - 0 or more horizontal whitespaces.

Since it is a PCRE pattern, `perl=TRUE` is required.

Comment: I've not come across the h and z operator before. Thanks for this

Answer (score 0):

I think we can use negative lookahead regex.

```
gsub('\n(?!$)', ' ', mytext, perl = TRUE)

#[1]"There is a lot of stuff"    "There is a lot of stuff\n"                        
#[3]"There is a  lot of stuff"   "Stuff is everywhere     around here. Clean it  up"
```

This will replace all the `\n` except for the ones which are at the end of the string.